# Medium-sized graph won't build

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import, version-10

Why can't Mathematica import a 40-KB file ([mediumEWD.txt](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/mediumEWD.txt)) and build the underlying graph in some decent time? I waited a minute, nothing.

```
import[file_String, customOptions___] :=
 Module[{lines, vertices, edges},
  lines = Import[file, "Lines"];
  vertices = Range@ToExpression@First@lines;
  edges = Map[
    With[{s = ToExpression@StringSplit@#},
      Property[
       (* from zero- to one-based indicies *)
       (s[[1]] + 1) \[DirectedEdge] (s[[2]] + 1),
       EdgeWeight -> s[[3]]]] &, Drop[lines, 2]];
  Graph[vertices, edges,
   customOptions,
   ImageSize -> Small,
   VertexSize -> Medium,
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   EdgeStyle -> Thick]]
```

Much smaller file ([tinyEWD.txt](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/tinyEWD.txt)) does get built in a moment. The data file format has the number of vertices and edges in the first two lines, followed by all the edges u -> v (weighted w).

```
V
E
u1 v1 w1
u2 v2 w2
...
```

I'm using Mathematica 10.3 on Windows 10 (64-bit).

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be just simplified. You could relabel vertices if you wish (and make into function):

```
tab = Import["http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/mediumEWD.txt", 
   "Table"];
gd = Drop[tab, 2];
g = Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ gd[[All, {1, 2}]], 
  EdgeWeight -> gd[[All, 3]]]
```

[image]

Checking weights:

```
(# -> PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ EdgeList[g])[[1 ;; 10]]
```

yields:

```
{244 \[DirectedEdge] 246 -> 0.11712, 
 246 \[DirectedEdge] 244 -> 0.11712, 
 239 \[DirectedEdge] 240 -> 0.10616, 
 240 \[DirectedEdge] 239 -> 0.10616, 
 238 \[DirectedEdge] 245 -> 0.06142, 
 245 \[DirectedEdge] 238 -> 0.06142, 
 235 \[DirectedEdge] 238 -> 0.07048, 
 238 \[DirectedEdge] 235 -> 0.07048, 
 233 \[DirectedEdge] 240 -> 0.07634, 
 240 \[DirectedEdge] 233 -> 0.07634}
```

Comment: `"Table"` simplification is nice, thanks. Importing the medium-sized file though still takes time, I abort after 10 seconds. Could this be version-specific? I don't understand.

Comment: @BoLe I don't understand your last comment. ubpdqn's code executes on your 40KB file almost instantaneously on my machine (win7-64 using MMA 10.3). Are you referring to a different data set? Are you using ubpdqn's implementation, or did you modify yours? Perhaps you could give more details.