# Creating a medium size graph with EdgeWeight is super slow

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, system-performance

I have discovered that creating medium-size (10k vertices, 40k edges) edge-weighted graphs takes impossibly long.

My motivation is solving AdventOfCode [2021 day 15](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/15), which can be formulated as a problem of finding the shortest path in an edge-weighted graph. The vertices of the graph correspond to the elements of a matrix. The vertices are connected horizontally and vertically but not diagonally, and the cost of moving from one to another is the value of the target element. For example, given a matrix

```
parse[s_] := ToExpression[Characters /@ StringSplit[s]];
a = parse@"1163751742
1381373672
2136511328
3694931569
7463417111
1319128137
1359912421
3125421639
1293138521
2311944581";
```

we can constructed a weighted graph:

```
weightedGraph[a_] := With[{n = Length@a},
   Graph[
    Cases[
     Flatten[
      Table[{x, y} \[DirectedEdge] # & /@ {{x, y - 1}, {x, 
          y + 1}, {x - 1, y}, {x + 1, y}}, {x, n}, {y, n}], 3],
     {_, _} \[DirectedEdge] {x_, y_} /; (1 <= x <= n && 
        1 <= y <= n)],
    EdgeWeight -> {{_, _} \[DirectedEdge] {x_, y_} :> a[[x, y]]}]];
g = weightedGraph@a
```

[image]

and find the lowest-cost path from the top left corner to the bottom right corner of the matrix (answer 40 matches the example in the AdventOfCode problem description).

```
lowestRisk[a_] := 
  With[{path = 
     FindShortestPath[weightedGraph@a, {1, 1}, Dimensions@a, 
      Method -> "Dijkstra"]}, 
   Total[a[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ Rest@path]];
lowestRisk@a (* 40 *)
```

I discovered that even for the smaller graph of Part 1, which corresponds to a 100x100 matrix, my lowestRisk calculation takes about 45 seconds, and apparently most of it is taken by weightedGraph (while I naively thought that somehow FindShortestPath is the culprit):

```
a = parse@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/jgKqC6DT", "Text"];
g = weightedGraph@a; // AbsoluteTiming (* {44.6422, Null} *)
```

Such a long calculation time makes solving Part 2, involving 500x500 matrices, completely impractical - the code to create the weighted graph takes many dozens of minutes, I stopped the calculation before it was even complete.

Am I missing something obvious here? Are there any faster ways to create weighted graphs?

**Update.**

The above effect can be demonstrated in a more straightforward way: using a graph construct inspired by EdgeWeight documentation page, compare the time it takes to create weighted graph:

```
In[63]:= Table[{2^n, 
  First@AbsoluteTiming[
    Graph[#[[1]] \[DirectedEdge] #[[2]] & /@ Tuples[Range[2^n], 2], 
      EdgeWeight -> {_?(OddQ[First[#]] &) -> -1}];]}, {n, 7}]

Out[63]= {{2, 0.000095}, {4, 0.000086}, {8, 0.000231}, {16, 
  0.001516}, {32, 0.023079}, {64, 0.301492}, {128, 4.52603}}
```

with time to create just the graph:

```
Table[{2^n, 
  First@AbsoluteTiming[
    Graph[#[[1]] \[DirectedEdge] #[[2]] & /@ 
       Tuples[Range[2^n], 2]];]}, {n, 7}]

{{2, 0.000067}, {4, 0.000053}, {8, 0.000107}, {16, 0.000377}, {32, 
  0.001166}, {64, 0.005321}, {128, 0.023285}}
```

Comment: It's slow because of the use of pattern matching in the edge weight specification. Look up `IGEdgeMap` in the IGraph/M package for a fast and convenient solution

Comment: I don't understand this. In my updated example above, EdgeWeight via rules for n = 7 takes 4 seconds. However, if we create an unweighted graph first `g = Graph[#[[1]] \[DirectedEdge] #[[2]] & /@ Tuples[Range[2^7], 2]];` (which takes 0.02 seconds), and manually apply the rules to the list of edges, e.g. `(EdgeList@g) /. {_?(Head[#] === DirectedEdge && OddQ[First[#]] &) -> -1, _DirectedEdge -> 0} // AbsoluteTiming`, it takes only another 0.02 seconds. Rule application should be very fast for such small lists.

Comment: I think it's a bug in EdgeWeight use with rules; I will report it to Wolfram.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with defining EdgeWeight via rules. A solution, inspired by [Medium-sized graph won't build](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99965/medium-sized-graph-wont-build), is to create the graph using an explicit list of edge weights:

```
edges[a_] := With[{n = Length@a},
  Cases[
   Table[{x, y} \[DirectedEdge] # & /@ {{x, y - 1}, {x, 
       y + 1}, {x - 1, y}, {x + 1, y}}, {x, n}, {y, n}],
   {_, _} \[DirectedEdge] {x_, y_} /; (1 <= x <= n && 1 <= y <= n), 
   Infinity]]

weightedGraph2[a_] := 
 Graph[edges@a, 
  EdgeWeight -> (a[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ (Last /@ edges@a))]

lowestRisk[a_] := 
 With[{path = 
    FindShortestPath[weightedGraph2@a, {1, 1}, Dimensions@a, 
     Method -> "Dijkstra"]}, 
  Total[a[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ Rest@path]]

lowestRisk@
  parse@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/jgKqC6DT", 
    "Text"] // AbsoluteTiming (* {0.287795, 390} *)
```